# "Read-only" and "Cannot allocate memory" error messages when trying to read or write to tape

Tags: 16.04, read-only

I have a computer running ubuntu 16.04 and I am trying to read and write to an LTO-4 tape using mt and tar commands.

I tried to rewind it using `mt -f /dev/st0 rewind` command, but there is simpl no reaction. The only command that does something is `mt -f /dev/st0 eject`.

When I try to write to it (`tar cvf /dev/st0 Test.txt`) it gives me "Filesystem is read-only" error.

`tar -tzf /dev/st0` gives me "Cannot allocate memory" error.

What is my issue?

Comment: Might it be a permissions issue? I.e., does `sudo mt -f /dev/st0 rewind` work?

Comment: Nothing happens when I run that command.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the tape needs erasing, use:

```
sudo mt -f /dev/st0 erase
```

You can check the status and see what's wrong using:

```
sudo mt -f /dev/st0 status
```